# javascript in masterpages ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net-2.0

I am trying to set up a masterpage that contains a javascript popup subroutine that can be used in multiple web pages. The popup already works in a single page environment. I now want to migrate it to a master page. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. I already searched this site and tried a couple of the suggestions to no avail. W small working example would help.
Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 1):

Just take what you have in your single page and place it in the master page.  It is really that simple.  :)  Then just replace the main body of the HTML in the master page with the content sections and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

> One thing I did discover was that for some reason the derived page had to be in the same folder as the master page.

Most likely caused by the master page referencing a subdirectory that works for the master page, but not the internal pages themselves. One workaround would be using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(string Key, string URL)
like so:
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude("uniqueIdentifier", "~/javascript/myjs.js");
```

Alternatively, you can embed the file as a resource and use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Page, Type, Key);
like so:
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(this.Page, typeOf(Page), "resourceKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) is my current favourite, seems to be most robust and flexible. Simply include the js files in your master then create an isntance on your pages

Answer (score 0):

be sure to use the scriptmanager class to add the javascript